# Analysis of binary variables

Tags: categorical-data, references, binary-data, exploratory-data-analysis

I have a data set consisting of about a quarter-million objects, each of which may have any of 30 particular features. So I might have

Object 1: feature 3, feature 7
Object 2: feature 3, feature 29, feature 30
Object 3: feature 3, feature 7
Object 4: feature 1, feature 18, feature 20, feature 28
...

At this point I'm just doing exploratory analysis. I'm interested in seeing how the different features relate: does 29 always appear with 30? Does feature 7 often occur with feature 3? Can feature 10 be predicted from features 1, 2, and 3? Etc.

What types of analysis are appropriate here? The problem is different from others I have worked on in the past because the state space is both small (each object 'holds' merely 30 bits of easily-compressible information) but paradoxically also large ($30 \choose 2$ is already too large to readily present, so even pairwise interactions are hard to study, and $30 \choose 3$ is much too large).

My immediate thought is something that would identify which pairs, triples, quadruples, etc. have 'interesting' interactions, even though examining them individually is infeasible. But perhaps there are more interesting things to do?

Basic references may be appropriate here (and would be appreciated if relevant).

Comment: Might be of interest: http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~saul/papers/logpca_aistats03.pdf

Comment: @leonbloy: That looks fantastic! I will read it carefully.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pairwise may be too large to present, but it's certainly not too large to explore. You could make a 30x29 table and have each cell be the number of cases where both are present. Then you can look. You might even do this for 3 way by looking at 27 such tables. See if you find anything interesting. Depending on how the frequency of data pairing, you might ease the visualization of a table by using colors.

In some cases you say "occur with" and in some you say "predict". If you have hypotheses about prediction you could use logistic regression.

Another purely exploratory idea is to run 30 logistic regressions, each predicting one variable from the other 29. The idea here wouldn't necessarily be to use the models as models, but to use them as tools. Just find big regression coefficients for exploration.

Yet another idea is to create a new variable equal to $\text{var30}*2^{30} + \text{var29}*2^{29} +  \dots $ then find which combinations occur most frequently.

Yet another idea is to do cluster analysis on the binary data.

(that should give you some things to explore!)

Comment: I'm curious about how the $30\times 29$ table and the $30\times 29\times 27$ table would be laid out, because it seems to me you would instead need the full $30\times 30$ and $30\times 30\times 30$ arrays. Also, how would logistic regression be superior to or any easier than exploring the $2\times 2$ subtables of the $30\times 30$ table? Finally, exactly how would you use the binary representation (your "new variable") to find *combinations*?

Comment: How exactly to do it would depend on software. 30x29 is all that's needed for 2 variables because (as I understand it) order is not important and each feature can occur a maximum of once. For 3 way, I would make 28 such tables.

Logistic regression seems easier because there would be 30 equations, each with 29 parameters - certainly not something you'd want to present or publish, but easier to explore than all the 2x2 subtables (I don't even want to think how many of those there are)

Comment: The new variable could be used to find combinations by seeing which numbers are most common and then figuring out through binary arithmetic what combinations those are. (I wanted to use base 10, but not sure how to get R to display 30 digit numbers).

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications: I had originally thought you meant to apply logistic regression one *explanatory* variable at a time.  The $30\times 29$ approach doesn't work, as far as I can see: what you're really talking about is a strict upper (or lower) triangular part of a $30\times 30$ matrix--a little less than half of it.  In the three-fold case, you're looking at a little less than one-sixth of a $30\times 30\times 30$ table, etc. The binary approach doesn't seem to get you very far, unless many of the cases are *identical*.

Comment: Thinking about it some more, I think you're right on the tables.

Comment: Some combinations (I would say "points on the 30-hypercube") do occur very frequently, it's very nonrandom. If I had to guess I'd say the most common alone accounts for > 20,000 objects.

Comment: And thank you, Peter, for this answer. It is a great starting point for my search. Thank you for taking my admittedly open-ended question seriously.

Comment: That's interesting, Charles. You do need to look at that in context, though: you would want to assess how many times that combination would occur by chance if all $30$ attributes were independent; this chance depends on the relative frequencies with which the various attributes occur.

Comment: @whuber: Agreed. It's much more than you'd expect assuming independence, though, with the probabilities as they are.

Comment: The tables might be better as heatmaps.  A short 30 frame film of heatmaps might be useful too.  Also, considering a  30 hypercube, a quarter million objects doesn't sound like very many.  There should be lots of holes here that you can ignore.

Answer (score 1):

OP describes categorical data and should use approaches from that domain. I highly recommend the netCoin package in R. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/netCoin/vignettes/netCoin.html It will check for coincidences using Haberman. By coincidences and co-occurrence here mean two features occurring on the same objects far more than chance. Haberman accounts for number of times each feature occurs and total number of objects but I think not for some objects having more features.Then netcoin will plot an interactive network graph with edges representing high coincidences. If you wish to compare objects instead of features just transpose the dataset. To test interactions (features 1, 2, 3, predict feature 10) user will have to create the columns themselves, such as multiplying the True False version of each feature. Alternatively vcd, Visualizing Categorical Data, could help. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/vcd/vignettes/strucplot.pdf . Features 1,2,3 predicting feature 10 is called conditional probability. Finally OP could try to predict each column using machine learning classification models and then trying to explain those models via packages like DALEX.

Comment: Although implementation is often mixed with substantive content in questions,
we are supposed to be a site for providing information about statistics, machine
learning, etc., not code or package recommendations. It can be good to provide those as well, but please
provide a substantive answer in text for people who don't use R.

Comment: @gung-ReinstateMonica The vignettes do a really good job explaining the statistics.